# Vim: extracting references surrounded by parentheses in a text document

Tags: vim

I would like to extract references from a large text document using Vim.  These references are surrounded by parentheses and may contain a single reference within the parentheses, or may contain multiple references within, e.g. Some taxa are found in North Atlantic (Oliver and Allen, 1980a) and others in Antarctic waters (Burne, 1920; Knudsen, 1970).  I am not sure whether it is better to try to extract the pattern (i.e. any text within parentheses), or whether to try to delete all text that does not match the pattern. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[This Vim Tips Wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy_the_search_results_into_clipboard) contains many approaches and alternative implementations to yank all matches of a pattern into a register.

You just need to come up with a pattern for your references (something like `/(\zs.\{-}\ze)/)`, put it in the function, and then you can paste the register contents into the same or a new buffer, and do any further processing (e.g. splitting multiple refs).